# Bifurcations where eigenvalues become purely imaginary

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, stability-theory, bifurcation

Say a system of 2 ODE's has the following Jacobian at a fixed point $(0,0)$,
$$
Df_{\mu}(0,0) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-(1/2 - \mu) & 1/2+\mu \\
-(1/2 + \mu) & 1/2-\mu 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{-2\mu}$. Clearly the eigenvalues are real and distinct for $\mu<0$, are both $0$ for $\mu=0$, and are complex conjugate for $\mu>0$. I've been searching for some references on such a bifurcation, which doesn't seem to resemble a Hopf bifurcation (where the real component of $\lambda$ is dependent on $\mu$, but not the imaginary component). Any recommendations or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is known as a saddle-center bifurcation.